# valueForKeyPathの戻り値（AnyObject?）のキャストについて

Tags: swift

```
class Test : NSObject {
   var testUint8: UInt8 = 0x00
   var testNSNumber: NSNumber = NSNumber(unsignedChar: 0x00)
}

var test1 = Test()
let a = test1.valueForKeyPath("testUint8") as! UInt8→(1)落ちる
let b = test1.valueForKeyPath("testNSNumber") as! NSNumber
```

ブレイクを張ってみたところ、下記のようになっており、想定ではUInt8の型となるのではと思っていたので、よくわからなくなっています。
bは (NsNumber) Int32(値)

ちなみに、(1)を

```
let a = test1.valueForKeyPath("testUint8") as! NSNumber
```

とすると落ちることはないのですが、やはり、
aは (NsNumber) Int32(値)
となってしまいます。
valueForKeyPathで取得する場合のキャストの方法が何かおかしいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valueForKeyPathの引数は文字列なので、
`valueForKeyPath(testUint8)`
ではなく
`valueForKeyPath("testUint8")`
になります。

また、valueForKeyPathの返り値はNSNumber?なので、Optionalを外した後、NSNumberから数値に変換する必要があります。例題の場合でしたら、
`let a = (test1.valueForKeyPath("testUint8") as! NSNumber).unsignedCharValue`
でUint8型の結果が得られるはずです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
すいません、valueForKeyPath引数にダブルクオーテーションが抜けていました。修正します。
なるほど。。。「Optionalを外した後、NSNumberから数値に変換」！勉強になりました。ありがとうございます。